# Django model returns None in AppConfig

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to fetch values from mysql database using django model inside an appconfig subclass but I keep getting None.

```
class myappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
     def ready(self):
        from .models import myModel
        mydata = myModel.objects.values('A')
```

Even though there is data in the mysql table corresponding to myModel, the value in mydata is None.
What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: First of all, what is the ***"purpose"*** this value fetch?

Comment: The data is used very frequently in different places in the application. Hitting the DB every time the data is needed does not make sense as it make the app very slow. The purpose is to store it in a cache when the server starts.

Comment: If you want cacheing, might I suggest `memcache` or `redis`, both of which integrate nicely and in a proven way with Django.

Comment: BTW, not sure if it's a copy/paste thing here or if it's in your source code, but your indentation on the `def`is off by a space ... that will be causing problems.

Comment: @urbanespaceman yeah that's a copy/paste issue. And yes I am planning on using memcached or redis, which is why I want this data to be available to be stored in a cache in memory when the server starts. That's where the I am facing the problem.

Comment: I don't think there's any point with that - memcache and redis load the data if they don't have a "clean" version in the cache. I suspect that trying to "enhance" this with "tricks" of your own will cause more problems than it solves. Why not just implement a caching solution first, and only then look and see if you have extra issues to be solved? Remember: don't pre-optimise :)

Comment: I'll give you an example to make my point. One use case is a search feature wherein the typeahead needs to be populated as the user types in the first few letters. If I don't have this data in memory, the DB hit takes time to fetch the data which in turn affects the user experience. I understand there are frameworks for this such as Lucene, but as of now I have not explored them.  @urbanespaceman

Comment: But that overhead would be for one user, the first time the DB is hit - after that it wouldn't happen. I get trying to force the cache load, but if you've not yet implemented a cache why are you trying to optimise somethign that'snot yet in place?